# Constraints for nls coefficients

Tags: r, nls

I'm trying to fit data with `nls()` function where the nature of data gives me bounds for one coefficient and for sum of two coefficients. Let me introduce short example to see where is the problem. I want parameter b1 to be between 0 and 1 and I want sum of parameters b1 and b2 to be between 0 and 1 as well.

```
set.seed(123)

# example where everything is OK
x <- 1:200
g <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.5)
y <- 3 + (0.7 + 0.2 * g) * x 
yeps <- y + rnorm(length(y), sd = 0.1)  

# both parameter b1 and sum of parameters b1 and b2 are between 0 and 1
nls(yeps ~ a + (b1 + b2 * g) * x, start = list(a = 0.12345, b1 = 0.54321, b2 = 0.4213))

# using more extreme values
x <- 1:200
g <- rbinom(200, 1, 0.5)
y <- 3 + (0.9 - 0.99 * g) * x 
yeps <- y + rnorm(length(y), sd = 15) 

# b1 is OK, but b1 + b2 < 0
nls(yeps ~ a + (b1 + b2 * g) * x, 
    start = list(a = 0.12345, b1 = 0.54321, b2 = 0.4213))

# trying constraints, not good, sum is still out of range
nls(yeps ~ a + (b1 + b2 * g) * x, 
    start = list(a = 0.12345, b1 = 0.54321, b2 = 0.4213),
    lower = list(a = -Inf, b1 = 0, b2 = -1),
    upper = list(a = Inf, b1 = 1, b2 = 1),
    algorithm = "port")
```

What I'm looking for is something like that (does not work):

```
nls(yeps ~ a + (b1 + b2 * g) * x, 
    start = list(a = 0.12345, b1 = 0.54321, b2 = 0.4213),
    lower = list(a = -Inf, b1 = 0, b2 = -b1),
    upper = list(a = Inf, b1 = 1, b2 = 1 - b1),
    algorithm = "port")
```

Is it possible to set constraints with other parameters in `nls()` function? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have a look on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11589139/707145).

Comment: Thanks for hint. However, I'm not sure if `ifelse` is good approach in `nls` function, see e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14561/specifying-parameter-constraints-in-nls

Comment: Anyway, how does this approach differ from fitting two models for - each `g` group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let B2 = b1+b2 so b2 = B2-b1 and substituting B2-b1 for b2 we get a problem in terms of a, b1 and B2 of which the latter two are between 0 and 1 so:

```
fm <- nls(yeps ~ a + (b1 + (B2-b1) * g) * x, lower = c(-Inf, 0, 0), upper = c(Inf, 1, 1),
    start = list(a = 0.1, b1 = 0.5, B2 = 0.1), alg = "port")
```

giving the following (hence b2 = B2 - b1 = 0 - 0.9788 = -0.9788)

```
> fm
Nonlinear regression model
  model: yeps ~ a + (b1 + (B2 - b1) * g) * x
   data: parent.frame()
      a      b1      B2 
-5.3699  0.9788  0.0000 
 residual sum-of-squares: 42143

Algorithm "port", convergence message: both X-convergence and relative convergence (5)
```

and plotting:

```
plot(yeps ~ x)
points(fitted(fm) ~ x, pch = 20, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is much more elegant solutions. Thanks for this hint!